# Pip Error Offline Installation from a Requirements.txt?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, pip, package

I'm trying to install Rasa (it's a python pip package) in a Ubuntu VM that has no internet connection. I use a requirements.txt to install rasa completely offline. The requirements.txt and the packages (.whl files) are in the same folder. I use following command:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links /home/...(folder with .whl files) -r requirements.txt
```

It collects the dependencies but stops after the "tensorflow" package. Here's the log:

```
(venv) [user@ubuntuvm alldependencies]$ pip install --no-index --find-links /home/user/alldependencies/ -r requirements.txt
Looking in links: /home/user/alldependencies/
Processing ./absl_py-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
[ PROCESSING bla bla....]
Processing ./tensorboard-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./tensorflow-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/home/user/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/home/user/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 391, in _resolve_one
    dist = abstract_dist.get_pkg_resources_distribution()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/wheel.py", line 29, in get_pkg_resources_distribution
    with ZipFile(self.req.local_file_path, allowZip64=True) as z:
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1108, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1175, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

What can I do? I installed Python 3.6 and the newest Pip Version (20.x).

Comment: `unzip -l tensorflow-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl`. If it doesn't work, the wheel is broken beyond repair. BTW it doesn't look like a valid wheel anyway, based on the platform tag - where did you get it from?

Comment: @hoefling It was created automatically. I have also an online ubuntu vm where I installed rasa. I created with pip freze and download all the requirements and .whl files and moved them with via usb to my offline vm.

Comment: Try using the wheel from pypi.org instead: [with GPU support](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/ad/769c195c72ac72040635c66cd9ba7b0f4b4fc1ac67e59b99fa6988446c22/tensorflow-2.3.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl), [CPU only](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/1a/0dff6c8421f84b2f104adf48c8ad8b9ae5a693417868abacfab9f133c122/tensorflow_cpu-2.3.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl).

Comment: @hoefling Thank you very much! Now it collects all the data files. But the installation failed. Here's the log:

Comment: @hoefling Found existing installation: six 1.11.0
    Uninstalling six-1.11.0:
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/opt/rh/rh-python36/.../six.cpython-36.pyc' -> '/tmp/pip-wd3_6z3t-uninstall/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/.../six.cpython-36.pyc'
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/rh/...s/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc'

Comment: That's another issue, related to permissions. `pip install --user pkgname ` or inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `tensorflow-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl` is corrupted. Possible causes are: something went wrong during the download or during the write on disk of this file. Most likely downloading it again would solve the issue.